# Faster select query for multiple primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

While testing my simple mail MySQL db, I found a strange behaviour and would be glad to know why.

My 'mail' table has two primary key :

```
idx : INT(Auto-Increment)
uid : VARCHAR(50)
```

with some other dummy columns like createdTime, info, etc.

Then, I've filled my table with 200,000 dummy datas, and tested with a simple search query :

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE uid='RANDOMGENERATEDUID';
```

It took about 0.235sec to execute this query, and from workbench's tabular explain I found out that this query performs full-table scan and uses no keys.

I was curious that what will happen if I *force* to use 'idx' column for SELECT query, so, I've tested out another query, which will have the same result :

```
SELECT * FROM mail
WHERE idx IN (SELECT idx FROM foodwagondb.mail WHERE uid='RANDOMGENERATEDUID');
```

But what surprised me was that this query executes way more faster, 0.078sec to execute!

What's going on behind my eyes here? I would be happy to know why this happens!

Comment: One reason could be that in the second sub-query you only select `idx` which can be retrieved directly from the index alone, without ever accessing the table itself. MySql may decide that when it also needs to select other fields (`*`), it becomes a little less interesting to use the index, and more interesting to "only" do table access. This decision can depend on several factors, which I am not aware of. But the above could be one element.

Comment: That's interesting... Since second query has much better performance, I'd rather go with this one. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudl avoid the `IN`  clause and use a `INNER JOIN` instead

```
SELECT m1.* FROM mail m1
INNER JOIN foodwagondb.mail m2 ON m2.idx = m1.idx 
WHERE idx m2.uid='RANDOMGENERATEDUID';
```

the IN clause  is equivalent to an OR condition an this implies the related  query is repaeat  for each values ..  the inner  join perform just a query and match the resulting values.

Anyway you could improved both the query using a proper composite index for uid to

```
create index my_index on mail (uid, idx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on IN clause! And yes, composite index accelerates execution time a lot, didn't know about that. Thought just setting up primary key would be sufficient but was not :P

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, you search each and every row based on a varchar field (uid).
In the second query, mysql pre-filters rows based on an indexed field (idx), then searches that subset for the text string. For smaller tables, you wouldn't see the difference, but for larger ones, it has a performance hit.
And @scaisEdge is right, INNER JOIN rules!